# Extreme slowdown Cloud vs VPS (Amazon, Jelastic)

Tags: java, php, mysql, performance, cloud

We are trying to move one of our web-services (Java) to the cloud from a development server, here are the details:

There is a PHP front-end, connecting to a Java-based web-service that is connected to a MySQL database (all requests to the database are sent from the web-service, the php part is communicating with the Java back-end only, no direct connection to the database).

**Start Point**

> Dev Server - CentOS (cPanel), 765MB-1.5GB RAM, 4CPU, Tomcat 7
>
> ***the software is running fast**, no speed issues, logs show normal CPU and memory usage

**Scenario #1**

> PHP front-end on Elastic Beanstalk and Java web-service with database on Elastic Beanstalk
>
> ***the software is about 80% slower**, logs show normal CPU and memory usage

**Scenario #2**

> PHP front-end on VPS (same company/location with Jelastic) and Java web-service with database on Jelastic
>
> ***the software is about 70% slower**, logs show normal CPU and memory usage

**Scenario #3**

> PHP front-end on VPS, Java web-service with database on Elastic Beanstalk and Jelastic (swithing)
>
> ***the software is about 70-80% slower**, logs show normal CPU and memory usage on both cloud environments

What I figured out, no matter where the PHP front-end is located, that will load fast, nothing to search here.

As soon as the Java back-end is moved from the VPS to the cloud (doesn't matter if Amazon or Jelastic), the whole software slows down extremely. Based on the logs and since we tried with two providers, this doesn't seem like a resource issue.

It cannot be a connection issue since we tried to have the PHP and Java in the same environment (Scenario #1).

It is either the Java web-service slowing down extremely (for unknown reason as logs show low resource usage) or it could be the connection between the Java application and the database (I doubt since in the first scenario, all three components are on Amazon, same environment, location).

Anyone ever had such an issue before? Any ideas? Thank you!

(note, I have zero experience with cloud hosting)

Comment: Something like this belongs on serverfault or superuser

Comment: You really need to connect a profiler to the Java back end, and actualy make some measurements and find out what specifically is slower (disk I/O? talking to the database? thrashing processes in and out of swap?) to figure this out.

One thing to keep in mind is that in general - and particularly with Amazon - I/O performance is much less predictable than on dedicated hardware.  There's a good chance I/O is your bottleneck (it usually is), but you need to know what actually is slow.

Comment: @Daryl Gill: Sorry, but this is nonsense. On SF/SU they'll say that it belongs to SO, or SU/SF, as it's too language specific or whatever. There are unbelievably many NIMBYs there.

Comment: @maaartinus Yes, this is a language specific question, but this is regarding normalized log recordings to a known performance hilt, members on the SU or SF community can give more specific diagnostic methods

Comment: @Daryl Gill: You might be perfectly right; I'm just saying that such cross-domain questions tend to be chased from site to site.

Answer (score 1):

For high performance Java cloud backend, you can try Jelastic implementation by Elastx - see the performance research that CloudSpectator did on them (they also used Amazon and Rackspace cloud in the study): http://blog.jelastic.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Elastx-Fueld-by-SolidFire-9-5-13+Jelastic.pdf

Also, I do not know who your current Jelastic provider is, but if you contact them by clicking **Help** / **Contact Support** in Jelastic dashboard, I am sure that they will be happy to troubleshoot the issue! If this does not help - please ping me offline.

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to specific parameters in configuration files, mostly for DB. Please double check that they are the same in each test. 
Also it is not clear how you measure performance and what "slower" exactly means. And you have not specified size of resources on Jelastic and EB. Please double check that resources are equal as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you are measuring is CPU an memory. Since both give normal results, and your application is communicating over the network, I'd suspect network latency to be the culprit. Next thing to look into would be for example disk I/O performance, which can slow down your application like having a handbrake.